# tablesorter filtering a date format dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: jquery, sorting, datetime, filter, tablesorter

I am using tablesorter to display date and I want the format of `dd-mm-yyyy` and I have this list of date.

```
Start Date
----------
08-05-2015
05-12-2015
24-07-2015
15-06-2015
17-05-2015
```

but when I sort it it will look like this form big to low value.

```
Start Date
----------
24-07-2015
17-05-2015
15-06-2015
08-05-2015
05-12-2015
```

is it possible that it will look like this?

```
Start Date
----------
05-12-2015
24-07-2015
15-06-2015
17-05-2015
08-05-2015
```

it can be ordered when I change the date forma into `mm-dd-yyyy` but is it possible for `dd-mm-yyyy` ?

I tried this code but seems nothing happen

```
$('#mytable').tablesorter({
   sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]], 
   dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yyyy',
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell if you're using the [original tablesorter](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter) (v2.0.5) or my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), so I'll answer for both:

- v2.0.5 - The only `dateFormat` options that are available are:

  - `"us"`
  - `"uk"`
  - `"pt"` (only available in the [master branch](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter/blob/master/jquery.tablesorter.js#L984))
  - `"dd/mm/yy"` or `"dd-mm-yy"`
- tablesorter fork [`dateFormat` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#dateformat) (currently v2.21.4)

  - `"mmddyyyy"` (default)
  - `"ddmmyyyy"`
  - `"yyyymmdd"`